# Titanium if attribute and Alloy.Globals not working

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

According to the documentation it is possible to:

> In the XML markup, add the if attribute to an element and assign it to the property passed to the createController() method. Prefix the property name with the $.args namespace. Based on the property passed to the method, the application displays a different label.

So this means that if I put:

```
<Label if="Alloy.Globals.property" color="blue">Foobar</Label
```

Wont work?? Right now I´m not using the createController method, because it is added on the XML by a Require tag. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Make sure `Alloy.Globals.property` is set before the view is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes-section-35621526_AlloyStylesandThemes-CustomQueryStyles) there are some examples.

One of which:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <Label if="$.args.fooBar" color="blue">Foobar</Label>
        <Label if="$.args.fooBaz" color="red">Foobaz</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

So yes, this will just work. As long as the property you provide is already set when rendering. Once your variable changes while the view is open it won't update it. For that you'll need [data binding](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding)